# MSVS 2010 C++ Compiler and Stack alignment issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, calling-convention

My problem is MSVS 2010 C++ compiler is generating code in a way after returning from a function call resolved in runtime(GetProcAddress+GetModuleHandle) from another dll the compiler then tries to align stack this way:

```
   CALL DWORD PTR DS:[2000367C]             ;  apiresolvedinruntime.dll
   ADD ESP,12                               ;  <- this is the stack alignment
```

This is of course overwriting the return address and my program crashes, can someone explain me why compiler aligning the stack when it really shouldn't do it?

Comment: Please post (a) the declaration of the function in the module, (b) how you obtain the function pointer via `GetProcAddress`, and (c) how you call the function.

Comment: Sounds like a calling convention mismatch: __stdcall vs. __cdecl, perhaps.  Did you correctly annotate the type of the function pointer with the one that matches the function you're calling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't call the runtime loaded function using the correct calling convention. Calling convention specifies the default handling of what happens to the stack. Most likely, the DLL was compiled using the `__stdcall` calling convention (which is what e.g. the Windows DLLs use), which specifies that the called function is supposed to clean up the stack, but the calling code was declared with a function pointer using the `__cdecl` calling convention (which is the default). Under `__cdecl`, functions support variadic arguments, so the caller needs to do the cleanup of the stack, because the called function does not know how many arguments are passed.

You need to verify that the DLL and the calling code are compiled using the same calling conventions.

Comment: FWIW, this issue gets masked on x64, as these two calling conventions are the same in the Windows x64 ABI.

Comment: @Reuben: That is because on amd64 there is a standard calling convention (which is equivalent to `__fastcall` on x86). x86 never has had a standard calling convention. (`__fastcall` is more useful on x64 processors because there are more registers available)

Comment: Yes, I know :)  I was just leaving this information here as background material for the question.  FWIW, while it's in the spirit of __fastcall on x86, it's not entirely equivalent as I understand it; stack alignment, number of args that can fit in registers, required spill space for args in registers, etc. all seem to differ.

Comment: you're right, working with third party software is a hell, diferent calling conventions was the problem, thanks

Comment: @reuben: Yes, it's not *exactly* the same -- but it works the same way. (Namely, that lots of arguments are passed through registers instead of through the stack) The differences are the result of alignment requirements in long mode and the fact that more registers are available in long mode.

Comment: @billy, so it's not possible at all working with dlls with diferent calling conventions? very interesting, let's supose we need 2 dlls which were developed by someone else with diferent calling conventions, is it possible to work with both of them?

Comment: @user615741: It's entirely possible. You just need to declare the function pointer in the caller with the right convention. e.g. `PVOID (__stdcall *FooBarFunc)(int, int int)`. (Another example is [here](https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/instalog/src/a955c1cb421a/LogCommon/DdkStructures.h#cl-596) -- note NTAPI is a macro for `__stdcall` because that's what Windows uses)